# PayPal Adaptive Payment iOS Approval URL (Maybe MPL and new iOS SDK)

Tags: ios, node.js, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

first in my iOS project i have to include a payment which i can only i achieve with the Adaptive Payment Flow. I have to ensure that the users has a valid paypal account, for what i use the "new" iOS SDK. Later after some action, i create on the Server Site a payment with the https://github.com/Ideame/paypal-adaptive-sdk-nodejs. The Backend is creating me a pre approval url which works fine in the browser. Now my question how should i handle this url on mobile, i tried it in a web view, which looks terrible and don't works for some reasons which i don't know, anyway it is bad for me that i don't have then any callbacks to check if the buy was successfully. I tried also do integrate the old mpl paypal library, but i cant add it to my project because there a duplicated files in the old and the new paypal lib. Did anybody have a hint, how to accomplish my use case?